# How to read 12h (AM/PM) timeformat in gnuplot

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

I want to generate some nice graphs by using existing and auto generated data files. Unfortunately I cannot change the format of the files.

The lines contain a timestamp and a value. e.g.

```
July 06, 2014 at 12:46PM 84.6
```

In Gnuplot I can use the given format identifier to read the timestamp. But there is no possibility to separate between AM oder PM time.

```
set timefmt "%B %d, %Y at %H:%M"
```

Any suggestions on this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `awk` script will format your file:

```
awk '{time = $5; if(substr(time,6,2) == "PM" \
&& substr(time,1,2) < 12) add = 12; else add = 0; \
$5 = substr(time,1,2)+add "" substr(time,3,3); \
print $0}' data
```

so that

```
July 06, 2014 at 10:46AM 83.6
July 06, 2014 at 12:46PM 84.6
July 06, 2014 at 10:46PM 85.6
```

will look like

```
July 06, 2014 at 10:46 83.6
July 06, 2014 at 12:46 84.6
July 06, 2014 at 22:46 85.6
```

within gnuplot you can do this dynamically when plotting your file. You can do (note I need to escape the `"`):

```
set timefmt "%B %d, %Y at %H:%M"
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M"
plot "< awk '{time = $5; if(substr(time,6,2) == \"PM\" \
&& substr(time,1,2) < 12) add = 12; else add = 0; \
$5 = substr(time,1,2)+add \"\" substr(time,3,3); \
print $0}' data" u 1:6 w l
```

[image]

Note I am assuming that 00:15 is 00:15AM. If your output is 12:15AM then you need to modify the script accordingly. Something along these lines:

```
if(substr(time,6,2) == "AM" && substr(time,1,2) == 12) add = -12
```

Comment: Just a note for future-self and others. The "data" in the end is the filename of the data. In case you give in the filename as a variable you need to concatenate it properly. For example "filename", then the end should look like this
`int $0}' ".filename u 1:6 w l`

Comment: just for the records... from gnuplot 5.4.0 on, `%p` can take `AM`,`am`,`PM`, and `pm` as input format. For gnuplot 5.2.0 you can use a workaround, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59552645/7295599