# Using GNUplot to show time data with AM/PM

Tags: gnuplot

Have some data looks like this:

`7:02:23PM,0.48
    7:02:24PM,0.472
    7:02:25PM,0.483
    7:02:26PM,0.453
    7:02:27PM,0.466
    7:02:28PM,0.45`

I tried doing `set timefmt  "%I (or l) :%M:%S%p"` and `set xdata time` but I get nothing but "Bad time format in string" errors. Clearly my syntax is off but I can't for the live of me figure out a working permutation. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886293/how-to-read-12h-timeformat-in-gnuplot/

Comment: the solution there simply removes the am/pm beforehand. gnuplot supposedly supports am/pm.

Comment: No, gnuplot supports am/pm only for the output (in `set format x`), but not for parsing input data. For supported specifiers see the docs for timefmt.

Comment: I see, I thought since there was a %p it applied to in as well as out. that makes sense.

Comment: @PaulL You don't need to do the processing beforehand. As explained in the answer you can use the `awk` script dynamically from within gnuplot by fixing the input.