# change hour format gnuplot (substract 12 hour)

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

I have two devices working in paralell, the problem is that one of them was set up 12 hours different than the other (that is, instead of 17:00, marked 05:00). 
I'm trying to apply this solution:
[How to read 12h (AM/PM) timeformat in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886293/how-to-read-12h-am-pm-timeformat-in-gnuplot)

In this way: My data are like this:

```
#Time   Concentration (#/cm³)   
05:00:14    5902    
05:00:15    5898    
05:00:16    5989    
05:00:17    5921
```

And I'm running the folowing code:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set format x '%H:%M'  
set xlabel "time"

plot  "< awk '{time = $1; if substr(time,1,2) <= 12) add = 12; else add = 0}' data1.txt" u 1:2 t 'CPC1' w l, \
      "data2.txt" u 1:2 t 'CPC2' w l

pause -1
```

However, the treated data1 file is not being plotted, only the data2 which has the correct timescale. Any idea of solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the 12 hours directly inside gnuplot. Inside the `using` statement use `timecolumn` to get the time in seconds and then add your 12 hours (43200 seconds)

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set format x '%H:%M'  
set xlabel "time"
set style data lines

plot 'data1.txt' using (timecolumn(1) + 43200):2 t 'CPC1',\
     'data2.txt' using 1:2 t 'CPC2'
```

Comment: Do you have any clue why time values are not accessible via `($1)` calculations?