# Adjust time values in the using statement

Tags: time, gnuplot

I try to compare two data files that show the raise in memory consumption vs. time. The data stems from two tests that I executed on different times, I'm trying to make the difference (or equivalence) obvious by shifting the second plot in the x and y axes.

Here is my `test.plt` script (the `plot` line is wrapped for this question):

```
reset

set title "Memory consumtion of process"
set style data fsteps
set xlabel 'Zeit (HH:MM:\nSS.ddd)'
set timefmt '"%H:%M:%S"'
set xdata time
set xrange ['"10:00:00"' : '"13:00:00"']
set yrange [12000 : 20000]
set ylabel "Memory\nin KBytes"
set format x "%H:%M:\n%.3S"
set grid
set key left

plot 'mem-2015-11-26-1229.dat' using 1:2 with lines,
  'mem-2015-11-26.dat' using 1:($2-1500) with lines
```

There is no problem with y since this is a normal scalar value. But I'm having difficulties to do the same with the x axis, this is how I tried to shift x (all with no success):

```
plot 'mem-2015-11-26-1229.dat' using 1:2 with lines,
  'mem-2015-11-26.dat' using ($1-3600.0):($2-1500) with lines
```

Not even using the alias `($1)` seems to work on time axis:

```
plot 'mem-2015-11-26-1229.dat' using 1:2 with lines,
  'mem-2015-11-26.dat' using ($1):($2-1500) with lines
```

Both give the following warning (and no output for the second file):

> "test.plt", line 15: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

What am I doing wrong? Is it even **possible to calculate time values** at all? If yes, how?

Comment: See e.g. [change hour format gnuplot (substract 12 hour)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32948951/2604213) about calculations with times.

Comment: @Christoph Ok, that works :-) Thanks. But `timecolumn` isn't easy to find (or guess), it seems not very consistent, but time seems to be always handled somewhat special.

Comment: About consistency, I don't agree. Remember, that `$1` is merely a shortcut for `column(1)` which gives you the numerical value of a column. If you want to have the string value you must use `strcol(1)`, and for time values `timecolumn(1)`.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for correcting my POV -- I think, like most gnuplot beginners, I had only a short look on a few small examples and then "started to be productive" ;-) (today I learned that '$1' is only a shortcut)