# gnuplot: how to convert 12h time format into 24h time format?

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

How can I convert the annoying 12h time format (with AM and PM) into the 24h time format?

I wanted to avoid external programs like `awk` as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888332/7295599).

Since gnuplot has a time-specifier `%p` for "am" and "pm" (check `help time_specifiers`), I thought it would be easy. But the following code does not give the correct result, but a warning message:

> warning: Bad time format in string

Maybe, I'm using `%p` incorrectly?

**Code:**

```
### change 12h time format to 24h format (does not give correct results)
reset session

$Data12 <<EOD
12/31/19  8:12:01 AM
12/31/19  8:12:02 PM
12/31/19 12:00:03 am
12/31/19 12:00:04 pm
EOD

myTimeFmt12 = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p"
myTimeFmt24 = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"

set table $Data24
    plot $Data12 u (strftime(myTimeFmt24,timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt12))) w table
unset table
print $Data24
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
         "tbTime12to24.plt" line 15: warning: Bad time format in string
         "tbTime12to24.plt" line 15: warning: Bad time format in string
         "tbTime12to24.plt" line 15: warning: Bad time format in string
         "tbTime12to24.plt" line 15: warning: Bad time format in string
 31.12.2019 08:12:01    
 31.12.2019 08:12:02    
 31.12.2019 12:00:03    
 31.12.2019 12:00:04
```

Comment: Will be available in next version, https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/3d7d6d22d818b8fa8d14ee7698b56fdf845e37b3/

Comment: thank you for the good news. I don't know if besides "AM/PM" and "am/pm", some strange programs might even generate "a.m./p.m."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a somewhat "lengthy" solution I have come up with by defining my own formula, although I was hoping for a short "gnuplot-integrated" solution.

**Code:** (*edit:* simplified workaround for gnuplot >=5.2.0, covers `a.m.` and `p.m.` as well)

```
### change 12h time format to 24h format
reset session

$Data12 <<EOD
12/31/19  8:12:01 AM
12/31/19  8:12:02 a.m.
12/31/19  8:12:03 PM
12/31/19  8:12:04 p.m.
12/31/19 12:00:05 am
12/31/19 12:00:06 a.m.
12/31/19 12:00:07 pm
12/31/19 12:00:08 p.m.
EOD

myTimeFmt12 = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
myTimeFmt24 = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"

# change 12h am/pm format to 24h format
myTime12to24(colT,colM) = (_t = timecolumn(colT,myTimeFmt12), _p=strcol(colM), \
                          strftime(myTimeFmt24, _t + 12*3600*( \
                          ((_p eq "PM" || _p eq "pm" || _p eq "p.m.") ? 1 : 0) + (floor(_t/3600)%12==0 ? -1 : 0))))

set table $Data24
    plot $Data12 u (myTime12to24(1,3)) w table
unset table
print $Data24
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
31.12.2019 08:12:01
31.12.2019 08:12:02
31.12.2019 20:12:03
31.12.2019 20:12:04
31.12.2019 00:00:05
31.12.2019 00:00:06
31.12.2019 12:00:07
31.12.2019 12:00:08
```

**Code:** (since gnuplot >=5.4.0, `%p` is also implemented as input format, but it is not intended to cover `a.m.` and `p.m.`. I agree that not all variations of this unfortunate time format can be taken into account.)

```
### change 12h time format to 24h format
reset session

$Data12 <<EOD
12/31/19  8:12:01 AM
12/31/19  8:12:02 a.m.
12/31/19  8:12:03 PM
12/31/19  8:12:04 p.m.
12/31/19 12:00:05 am
12/31/19 12:00:06 a.m.
12/31/19 12:00:07 pm
12/31/19 12:00:08 p.m.
EOD

myTimeFmt12 = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p"
myTimeFmt24 = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"

set table $Data24
    plot $Data12 u (strftime(myTimeFmt24,timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt12))) w table
unset table
print $Data24
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
31.12.2019 08:12:01
31.12.2019 08:12:02
31.12.2019 20:12:03
31.12.2019 08:12:04    # not correct
31.12.2019 00:00:05
31.12.2019 12:00:06    # not correct
31.12.2019 12:00:07
31.12.2019 12:00:08
```