# gnuplot - Read Double Quoted datetime stamp

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying learn gnuplot and I want to to plot some comma separated data.

- x axis datetime stamp - enclosed in double quotes - containing a comma separator,
- y axis integer value data.

```
"1/31/22, 4:36",0
"1/31/22, 16:30",1
"1/31/22, 16:39",2
"2/1/22, 16:44",3
"2/1/22, 9:25",4
"2/7/22, 13:59",5
"2/7/22, 8:57",6
"2/8/22, 11:03",7
"2/18/22, 15:50",8
"2/21/22, 11:11",9
"2/24/22, 9:11",10
```

How do I read this data and plot in gnuplot?
I tried the following but get error about "warning: Skipping data file with no valid points"

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "\"%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M\""
set format x “%d/%m/%Y”
set datafile separator ","
plot "file.txt" using 1:2 with linespoints
```

I assume my timefmt is incorrect.  What is the correct syntax?

Also can gnuplot process datetime stamps in the following format with AM/PM?

```
"1/31/22, 4:36 AM",0
"1/31/22, 4:30 PM",1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `help time_specifiers`. Your year it 2 digits `%y` not 4 digits `%Y`.
The double quotes will make your date/time the first column. No need for extra double quotes in the format.

With the syntax `set xdata time` and `set timefmt "..."` you have only one format in the plot command.
If you are using the syntax `timecolumn()` (check `help timecolumn`) you can use different input time formats in your plot command.

**Note:** the format `%p` as input format has been introduced in gnuplot 5.4.0
For older versions you have to use a workaround, see e.g. [gnuplot: how to convert 12h time format into 24h time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59552645/7295599)

**Code:**

```
### plot timedata in double quotes and AM/PM format
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
"1/31/22, 4:36",0
"1/31/22, 16:30",1
"1/31/22, 16:39",2
"2/1/22, 16:44",3
"2/1/22, 9:25",4
"2/7/22, 13:59",5
"2/7/22, 8:57",6
"2/8/22, 11:03",7
"2/18/22, 15:50",8
"2/21/22, 11:11",9
"2/24/22, 9:11",10
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
"1/31/22, 4:36 AM",0
"1/31/22, 4:30 PM",1
"1/31/22, 4:39 PM",2
"2/1/22,  4:44 PM",3
"2/1/22, 9:25 AM",4
"2/7/22, 1:59 PM",5
"2/7/22, 8:57 AM",6
"2/8/22, 11:03 AM",7
"2/18/22, 3:50 PM",8
"2/21/22, 11:11 AM",9
"2/24/22, 9:11 AM",10
EOD

set datafile separator comma

myTimeFmt1 = "%m/%d/%y, %H:%M"
myTimeFmt2 = "%m/%d/%y, %H:%M %p"
set format x "%d/%m/%Y" time

plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt1)):2 w lp pt 7 ps 2 lc "grey" lw 4 ti "Data1", \
     $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt2)):2 w lp pt 7 ps 1 lc "red"  lw 1 ti "Data2"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]