# gnuplot format timestamp date and time AM PM with awk

Tags: awk, timestamp, gnuplot

Can sombody help me format the following timestamp for gnuplot with awk:

```
Jul 9, 2020 11:59:59 AM
Jul 9, 2020 12:00:00 PM
Jul 9, 2020 1:22:24 PM
```

I have been trying to adapt the code sample shown in the previous post but it does not work for me.

```
plot "< awk '{time = $4; if(substr($5,1,2) == PM \
&& substr(time,1,2) < 12) add = 12; else add = 0; \
$4 = substr(time,1,2)+add "" substr(time,3,6); \
print $0}' Test.csv" using 1:9
```

I always get the "x range is invalid" error from gnuplot. I am a totall beginner in coding.

A simillar question has been answered here: [How to read 12h (AM/PM) timeformat in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886293/how-to-read-12h-am-pm-timeformat-in-gnuplot)
But I am not able to adabt the code to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use awk if you can do it with gnuplot?
In general, this AM/PM time format is pretty painful.
As far as I know, gnuplot 5.2 cannot read AM/PM times as input, but I guess it should be implemented in newer versions.

The code below is slightly modified from here: [gnuplot: how to convert 12h time format into 24h time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59552645/7295599)
Maybe, it can still be a bit simplified. The data is converted into a reasonable format into `$Data2` and then it is plotted.

**Code:**

```
### time formatting with AM/PM
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Jul 9, 2020  12:22:24 AM    1.23
Jul 9, 2020  11:59:59 AM    2.34
Jul 9, 2020  12:00:00 PM    3.45
Jul 9, 2020   1:22:24 PM    4.56
Jul 10, 2020  1:22:24 PM    5.67
EOD

myTimeFmt12a = "%b %d, %Y"
myTimeFmt12b = "%H:%M:%S"
myTimeFmt24 = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"

# change 12h am/pm format to 24h format
myTime12to24(t,p) = t+12*3600*(floor(t/3600)<12 && (p eq "PM" || p eq "pm") ? \
                    1 : floor(t/3600)==12 && (p eq "AM" || p eq "am")  ? -1 : 0)

my12to24(colDate,colHours,colAMPM) = strftime(myTimeFmt24,timecolumn(colDate,myTimeFmt12a) + \
         myTime12to24(timecolumn(colHours,myTimeFmt12b),strcol(colAMPM)))

myInputTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
myOutputTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M:%S"
set format x myOutputTimeFmt timedate

set table $Data2
    plot $Data u (my12to24(1,4,5)):6 w table
unset table
print $Data2

plot $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myInputTimeFmt)):3 w lp pt 7 notitle  
### end of code
```

**Addition:** (With gnuplot 5.4 it will simplify to this:)

```
### time formatting with AM/PM (gnuplot 5.4)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Jul 9, 2020  12:22:24 AM    1.23
Jul 9, 2020  11:59:59 AM    2.34
Jul 9, 2020  12:00:00 PM    3.45
Jul 9, 2020   1:22:24 PM    4.56
Jul 10, 2020  1:22:24 PM    5.67
EOD

myInputTimeFmt = "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p"
myOutputTimeFmt = "%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M:%S"
set format x myOutputTimeFmt timedate

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myInputTimeFmt)):6 w lp pt 7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have installed gnuplot 5.4 and it can handle the AM PM timeformat.

Comment: ok, so what's the problem then? Check `help time_specifiers`. In newer versions `%p` should handle AM/PM also as input (earlier it was just output).